# Use of the present continuous to refer to timetabled events

Tags: time, present-tense, present-progressive, continuous-aspect

One of the things that is constantly confusing for English language learners, but comes with ease to native speakers, is when to use present continuous and when to use present simple.

Because of this, there are long lists of specific situations where students have to learn which tense is used for what.

For example, we use present simple for a re-occuring or habitual event "I walk home with Josh at 5:00pm" (implies this is a regular occurrence), whereas we use present continuous for a one off future planned event "I'm walking home with Josh at 5:00pm" (I'm doing that later today).

However, one thing that I keep seeing crop up in textbooks is the idea of "timetabled events".  This is always left undefined, and is not really clear what it means.  The typical example given is "the plane leaves at 3 tomorrow".

But honestly, I'm sure I'm just as likely to use the expression "the plane's leaving at 3 tomorrow."

Which tense to you think you would use, and should the use of the continuous here be viewed as "incorrect"?

Comment: It's a good question. However, what many learners consistently fail to understand is that English is a very context-dependent language.  On the face of it those sentences, in isolation, have exactly the same meaning -- and indeed they may do so -- in isolation. However in the real world, sentences do not occur in isolation.  Perhaps you could give some scenarios and then we can judge which is best for each.

Comment: Are there languages that aren't context dependent?

Comment: @deadrat no, but chasly does make a good point that English, more that many other languages, often depends heavily on context rather than syntax for meaning, due to its more lax/fluid/whatever you want to call it grammar.  Many romance languages have much more rigidly defined syntactical structures for past/future time continuous/one off events than English does for example.  Of course English is by no means unique in this regard, or the most extreme example.  But I feel we are disgressing/we digress.

Comment: @chasly How about the example I did give?  I can't think of an example of a "timetabled event" phrase that seems to require the present simple that isn't covered by the earlier requirement of a "re-occuring or habitual event".  In the Aeroplane example I already gave, I can't put my finger on any difference in meaning between PS or PC.  Moreover I can't think of a situation for a timetabled even that requires PS *not* PC

Comment: @Some_Guy I don't know whether chasly has made a good point or not, which is why I asked.  In particular, I don't know whether it's context that's important or idiom.  I'm given to understand that Chinese has no verb tenses, but the Chinese have no problem understanding temporal meanings.  I don't even know how to measure "laxness" or "fluidity" or "whatever" of a grammar.

Comment: @Some_Guy I think a native speaker would always use the present simple in the context of a timetable to say, "Flight 302 always leaves Laguardia at 3:00PM from Gate 32," and never the present continuous.  But for the unscheduled, "She is always leaving class to take a smoke break" is fine.

Comment: @deadrat - My point is that a deviation from habit can still be timetabled (see my answer)

Comment: deadrat: "Are there languages that aren't context dependent?"  - Did you hear the latest speech by the President or Prime Minister?

Comment: @deadrat "My plane's leaving at 7 tomorrow" feels perfectly natural to me, and I'm a native speaker.  Does it not to you?

Comment: @Some_Guy What have I said that would make you think not?

Comment: @deadrat " I think a native speaker would always use the present simple in the context of a timetable to say, "Flight 30..."  I'd use the present continuous to say, flight 302's leaving Laguardia at 3 tomorrow".  As for a recurring event, that's not where the ambiguity lies, it's with the amorphously defined "timetable" which, in all the resources I've read, is separate category to a habitual or recurring event.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I've looked at your answer, and I'm afraid I find it unhelpful.  And I'm fluent in English.  Between "contingency occurrence," "deviation from habit," "timetabled," "scheduled," and "habitual," I can't discern what rule you're describing.  But maybe because you're not trying to find a general rule in the face of those many possible contexts.  In any case, I think you get idiomatic English if you switch the simples for the continuous in your first **Example**.

Comment: @Some_Guy A timetable is a written form for a recurring event, so I'm not sure that you should rely on the resources you're reading.  It seems to me that the difference is in the general event (the flight in the timetable) and a particular occurrence (the flight at gate 32).  The former takes an enduring simple present, but not a  progressive; the latter takes either.  But I haven't tested this outside the airport.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many possible contexts that I shall focus on one difference that I see.

> The plane leaves at 3 tomorrow.

This is the scheduled and expected occurrence.

**Example**

"When does the plane leave?"

"Let me see -- the timetable says that the plane leaves at 3 tomorrow."

> The plane's leaving at 3 tomorrow.

This is a contingency occurrence.

**Example**

"When does the plane leave?"

"Well, according to the help-desk schedule, the plane is leaving at 3 tomorrow."

"That's surprising - doesn't it usually leave at 2.30?"

"Yes but there is a special flight passing through so things have been changed."

**Comment**

The latter event is timetabled -- it is scheduled. However it is not habitual.

Comment: Nice example. If the timetable were very loose, the 'is leaving' variant would probably also be used: 'The last plane off the island before winter is leaving at 3 tomorrow.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - agreed.

Comment: In the first example wouldn't "The plane's leaving at 3 tomorrow" be perfectly fine though?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK could you expand on "contingency occurrence".  When is it appropriate to use pres cont. for a "contingency occurence" and when the simple "will" future or going to, e.g. "according to the radio, it's going to rain tomorrow" NOT "according to the radio, it's raining tomorrow".

Comment: @Some-Guy Not for an unmarked statement concerning a 'scheduled and expected occurrence'. If you were just reading a timetable and passing on the information, you'd use 'leaves'. However, you might well use 'The plane's leaving at 3 tomorrow.' if it's 4 pm every other day, or if it's the first flight for the last  6 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good commentary--to simply answer your question:

*either tense is ok, and using the continuous is not incorrect.*